# How can I save the selected date picker value when clicked on an icon?

Tags: javascript

I am trying display a date picker when clicked on an icon. So far I am able to display the icon when clicked on the icon but I can not retrieve the selected value. Here is the code:

UI code

```
<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-configure aui-date-picker" id="edit-delete-date" style="cursor: pointer">Configure</span>
```

Javascript code

```
AJS.$('#edit-delete-date').datePicker({
    'overrideBrowserDefault': true}
);
var newDate = AJS.$("#edit-delete-date").val();
console.log("Print date" +newDate)
```

newDate is always null. How can I retrieve the selected value?

I also tried

```
var date = AJS.$('#edit-delete-date').datePicker({
        'overrideBrowserDefault': true}
    ).val();
```

but browser complains that `.val` is not a valid function

Comment: A `span` element doesn't have a `value` attribute. I'd suggest trying to apply the datepicker to a hidden input field, toggle the datepicker to display when the icon is clicked, and retrieve the value from the hidden field.

Comment: But that means I cannot use the icon?

Comment: No, that means you could bind a click event to the icon to trigger the datepicker.

Comment: I can already trigger the datepicker but I have trouble saving the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unable to retrieve a value from your `<span>` element, because it has no such property.

If you want to have a datepicker bound to a `<span>` element, without actually showing a separate `<input>` field, then I would suggest using a hidden input field.

```
<input id="date" type="hidden">
<span id="configure">Configure</span>
```

You can then bind a `click` event to the `<span>` element to trigger the `datepicker`.

```
$('#date').datepicker();

$('#date').on('change', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
});

$('#configure').on('click', (e) => {
    $('#date').datepicker('show');
});
```

Here's a basic working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrMyLp?editors=0010